# Luggage limit on Colombian buses?

Tags: luggage, buses, colombia

Does anyone know if this luggage limit is accurate? http://www.bolivariano.com.co/corporativo/preguntas-frecuentes?page=1

> Todo viajero tiene derecho a transportar como equipaje libre permitido, 15 kilos y/o 80cm de volumen. Si excede estos límites, debe cancelar aforo con el personal encargado de envíos de Bolivariano.

That just seems like a really small limit, especially compared to when I bused in Mexico and people seemed to be moving their entire estates by bus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I took these guys about three months ago and had luggage that was 20 - 25 kilos. It was not a problem whatsoever. And, my luggage wasn't close to the smallest nor lightest of what the passengers were transporting on my trip.

Answer (score 0):

The limit exists but is rarely enforced, never had a problem with several pieces of luggage